# RAPOR privacy enchanced statistics paper: I cannot understand the "Instantaneous randomized response"

Tags: privacy

I came across and studies [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.6981.pdf) paper with the title *RAPOR privacy enchanced statistics paper*. As it mentions the *Instantaneous randomized response* is calculated from the client as:

[image: Instantaneous randomized response is calculated]

Does that mean that it i-th bit will be 1 if the the B'i=1 with propability of `q`? And in the end in case of implementation how I will take account the propability `q`?

Comment: You would get a better answer on implementation part at either programming or Math stack exchange.

Comment: As for your first question, it means that if Bi' = 1, there is a probability q such that Si = 1